# Adding table borders to my table that has been created using Jinja

Tags: python, html-table, jinja2

I am trying to add borders to my tables that I have created using `Jinja`. From what I have found while testing with `<br>`s and even text. It looks like the tables get created **after** everything else gets rendered. Is this normal for `Jinja`?

I'm trying to get my tables to look like this:

[image: Table example]

This is from the W3 tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_table_borders.asp

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}

{%block content%} 
    <h1>{%block title%} 
        {% if name %} 
            {{name}} 
        {% endif %} 
        {% endblock %}
    </h1>

    <table class="table tablestriped">
        <tbody>
            <form action="/begin_edit_set" method="post">
                {%for date in dates %}
                <div>
                    <thead height="50px" vertical-align="bottom">
                        <th>{{date}}</th>
                        <th>Exercise</th>
                        {% for i in range(columns) %}
                        <th>Intervals</th>
                        <th>Resistance</th>
                        <th></th>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </thead>
                    {% for key, value in workouts[date].items() %}
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <!-- Key  is the name of the exercise -->
                        <td>{{key}}</td>
                        {% for i in value %}
                        <!-- Loop through the values to get all intervals, resistances, and edit buttons -->
                        {% if loop.index % 3 == 0 %}
                        <td><button type="submit" width="200" height="200" id="edit[]" type="button" name="edit-set" value="{{i}}">&#60-Edit</button></td>
                        {% else %}
                        <td>{{i}}</td>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <!-- <p>{{date}}</p>  Testing how tables get rendered. It looks like <p> gets rendered before any tables get created -->
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </form>
        </tbody>
        
        <style>
            
            table, th, td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
        </style>
{% endblock %}
```

I believe that my code is correct but I think that tables are created after some others things are done before.

My tables look like this:

[image: My table]

I think those broken lines in between the long line and my first table are borders but I think they are created before my tables are created. What is causing this?

Comment: This is not something specific to jinja. It's something related to CSS. Take a look at your css and see if anything is preventing the borders. Use your browser's dev tools to inspect the elements and their respective styles.

Comment: Looking into it. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction. I have noticed that if I create my own table the table head comes out with a border like expected. If I add a row to that table the borders disappear.